# Pandas custom accessor with instance variable

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to [extend](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/development/extending.html) `pd.DataFrame` with some extra functionality. I have the methods working fine, but I want to store some additional data as an instance variable, and I'm having unexpected trouble.

So far, I have:

```
@pd.api.extensions.register_dataframe_accessor('foo')
class Foo:

    def __init__(self, df):
        self._df = df

    @staticmethod
    def load_data(arg):
        data = doStuff(arg)
        obj = pd.DataFrame(data)
        # Remember how this object was made
        obj.__dict__['arg'] = arg
        return obj
```

(The awkward assignment to `obj.__dict__`, instead of just saying `obj.arg = arg`, prevents Pandas from treating this as an attempt to make a column. I learned to do this when I once subclassed DataFrame, which was quite a headache.)

Then I do:

```
obj = Foo.load_data('stuff')
obj.arg
obj.foo.arg
obj.foo._df.arg
```

Each of the last 3 lines leads to an `AttributeError`. I know I assigned the property... where did it go?

Comment: Can you verify from the outside that `arg` is contained in `obj.__dict__`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by saying in the method:

```
obj.foo.__dict__['arg'] = arg
```

and then:

```
obj.foo.arg
```